# find vector part of a quaternion in octave

Tags: octave, quaternions

I am working in octave. 
I have a quaternion vector  *q* . Let say it's scalar component is  *q1*  and the vector components are  *q2,q3,q4*  .
I need the values of  *q1,q2,q3,q4*  seperately using octave.
For example,

> if q = 1 + 2i + 3j + 4k
>   then q1 = 1 , q2 = 2 , q3 = 3 , q4 = 4 ;

I have googled but have not found any function to implement this in octave.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on the [sourceforge documentation page](http://octave.sourceforge.net/quaternion/function/quaternion.html)

```
octave:32> a=quaternion(1,2,3,4);
octave:33> a

a = 1 + 2i + 3j + 4k

octave:34> a.w

ans =  1

octave:35> a.x

ans =  2

octave:36> a.y

ans =  3

octave:37> a.z

ans =  4
```

Comment: I have downloaded the octave-quaternion package on ubuntu but I get an error when I try the constructor. Do I need to enable quaternions or use a different executable or something?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used matlab in quite a while, please try asking a new question, someone should be able to help.

Comment: @user50619 You need to do pkg load quaternion.